# how to save uncompressed outputs from a training job in using aws Sagemaker python SDK?

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to upload training job artifacts to S3 in a non-compressed manner.

I am familiar with the output_dir one can provide to a sagemaker Estimator, then everything saved under /opt/ml/output is uploaded compressed to the S3 output dir.

I want to have the option to access a specific artifact without having to decompress the output every time. Is there a clean way to go about it? if not any workaround in mind?
The artifacts of my interest are small meta-data files .txt or .csv, while in my case the rest of the artifacts can be ~1GB so downloading and decompressing is quite excessive.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the checkpoint path that is by default being synced with the specified S3 path in an uncompressed manner.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply specify an s3 location path to save your artifact within your training script. However I'm not totally sure that instances created by sagemaker have permission to directly write to S3, maybe they are also network isolated. I'm doing more or less what you say in order to read in real time tensorflow logs, but I'm using a custom image for the training. If you are interested you can take a look [here](https://github.com/roccopietrini/TFSagemakerDetection)

Comment: thank you, I tried what you describe but the EC2 instances don't have the AWS credentials logged in.. so you don't have permission

Comment: > I tried what you describe but the EC2 instances don't have the AWS credentials logged in

I don't think that's necessarily true. You should be able to get an AWS session within the container. Your IAM role that it assumes should have the credentials. You can manage S3 read access in that role.